# How to connect to Jira with basic authentication required?

Tags: apache, http, authentication, jira

I`m trying to set BASIC Authentication on HTTP component (camel ver. 2.14.1).

I`m looking for a way to setup basic auth. Something like in CXF spring bean and http:authorization properties.

```
<bean id="myAuth" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpConfiguration">
    <property name="authMethod" value="Basic"/>
    <property name="authUsername" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="authPassword" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="http" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
    <property name="camelContext" ref="myContext"/>
    <property name="httpConfiguration" ref="myAuth"/>
</bean>
```

and the route is:

```
    <route> 
        <from uri="timer://projectTimer?repeatCount=1" />
            <simple>http://10.47.2.203:8080/rest/api/2/project/TM</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="http://dontMatter" />
        <process ref="main" />

    </route>
```

I got an error:

Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by:          [org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException - HTTP operation  failed invoking http://10.47.2.203:8080/rest/api/2/project/TM with statusCode: 404]

What is the correct configuration for http basic authentication? 
Thanks for any advice.